# AVAudioPlayer causes my game to lag

Tags: xcode, avaudioplayer

I've made a simple game in Xcode where the character moves around the screen to collect coins, while avoiding getting hit by rocks.

For the movement I use NSTimers which work fine. The problem occurs when I add sound effects. I use AVAudioPlayers for this and it makes the game lag a little bit. I commented them out to see if they caused the problem, and it seems to be the case. I've looked around here on Stack Overflow and on other sites, but I can't seem to find a good answer. Any help appreciated!

Code:

```
- (void)CharacterMoving {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Character.frame, Rock.frame)) {

    [self performSelector:@selector(GameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.35];

    [Thousand play];
}

- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {

NSString *soundEffect=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"1000" ofType:@"mp3"];
Thousand=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundEffect] error:NULL];
Thousand.numberOfLoops=-0; 
}
```

Comment: Any code showing how you set up and play the sound with `AVAudioPlayer` would also be appreciated.

Comment: "For the movement I use NSTimers which work fine" No they don't. That's the worst possible way to create animated movement. Use actual animation (so that you're using the onboard animation server) or switch to Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used System Sound Services instead of AVAudioPlayer, and now it works perfectly.

This was very helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html